# Ionic ImagePicker - App crashed on IOS 12.3.1

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Submitting my app to the appstore, I had the surprise to get a rejection from Apple because of the app crashing when they (quoting them):

- Tapped on Add element button
- Tapped on Add a Photo
- Allowed camera roll access
- Tapped on Add a Photo again
- The app crashed

So that would be linked to my code :

```
    if(this.platform.is("cordova")) {
      this.imagePicker.hasReadPermission().then(
        (result) => {
          if (!result) {
            this.imagePicker.requestReadPermission().then(canRead => {
              if(canRead) {
                this.GetPicture();
              }
            });
          } else {
            this.GetPicture();
          }
        }, (err) => {
          this.imagePicker.requestReadPermission().then(canRead => {
            if(canRead) {
              this.GetPicture();
            }
          });
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  }

  GetPicture() {
    this.imagePicker.getPictures({
      maximumImagesCount: 1
    }).then(
      (results) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          // upload image to image service
        }
      }, (err) => console.log(err)
    );
  }
```

pretty vanilla stuff overall. So it would seem that when calling imagePicker.getPicture on latest IOS the app crashes.

Running Ionic 4.1.1, ImagePicker plugin version 2.3.3.

They also gave a few crash reports, attaching one of them if it can help.

[EDIT]

Symbolicated the crash log by doing

```
xcrun atos -o MyApp.app/Myapp -arch arm64 -l 0x104457fff -f attachment-6092491254159192914crashlog-E31E8DCE-AC53-4475-AD8D-476CA7E80FA3.crash
```

Not sure how the symbolicated report is said to help me...

[attachment-6092491254159192914crashlog-E31E8DCE-AC53-4475-AD8D-476CA7E80FA3.txt](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/ImagePicker/files/3414551/attachment-6092491254159192914crashlog-E31E8DCE-AC53-4475-AD8D-476CA7E80FA3.txt)

[symbolicated.txt](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/ImagePicker/files/3415030/symbolicated.txt)

Comment: Added symbolicated result... I'm not sure it can help :/

Comment: A symbolicatecrash tool helped me getting this : `Crash found at:
-[CDVInAppBrowser openInInAppBrowser:withOptions:] (in Azkara) (CDVInAppBrowser.m:163)` - can it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what it was - an issue with `inAppBrowser` plugin when calling `getPictures`. Updating `inAppBrowser` to the latest version fixed the issue :)

Comment: to what version?